# Is a GCM registration token with a colon valid?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am using the below code to get the DCM Registration token

```
 String token = "NoREG";
    try {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
         token = instanceID.getToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token", e);
    }
```

i am getting the registration token in an unusual format like

```
dsYKKXPzztU:APA91bH2J5OqK9OHEp7p5RUJ46fO_zPAEhEgPugJBviEqAbPyFhozMoVh1Npk_s_7wwyzaJ0LjiFki3PYFZHByw4KdA6Ke0XdudOqe4LPhNPA-Y2nbblRHLPhEp3dWyjqCTEsQhwHw24
```

as you can see it contains a colon, which makes me feel some thing is wrong. is this format correct??
please help

Comment: Have you tried whether it worked? If it does, it is correct. You shouldn't worry about how Google's API is functioning.

Comment: Yes I believe they are actually required to have a colon after the 10th or so character. The absence of the colon, now that would be worrisome

Answer (score 3):

The GCM registration token is usually around 140 chars in length, and can contain colons, underscores and hyphens. Maximum size is supposed to be 4k.

Comment: Having said this, I now see that none of my recent tokens (from Android devices) have colons in them! However, GCM is still working OK for me.

Comment: Hi @MagnusSmith. Is this still the case? If so, I was wondering if you can point me to a documentation? :)

Comment: These were observations from my own code. Sorry I did not record the documentation links I used. I see now that some people debate the 4k size, so perhaps I am wrong.