# Is a GCM Registration Token equal to the GCM Registration ID ?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i got confused by gcm today. I dont know if my registrationid is correct. I got characters and a colon in front of a registrationid starting with APA. The Pattern is xXXXxxX:APA...  . I implemented google cloud messaging for a android client using the example from here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client . If i use a older implementation (for example with GCMRegistrar) i only get a registration id starting with APA. Till now i though a registration id has to start with APA.

Is the stuff before the colon some tokenspecific stuff? Do i have to pass the full token to the webservice or is it okay if i cut the chars before the colon and send the registration starting with APA?

Comment: BTW: GCM is deprecated. Use FCM

Comment: GCM is not deprecated. they will support the current version of gcm but new features will be added to fcm as google announced. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Comment: @Igor It says gcm register is deprecated. I said gcm is not deprecated as a response to Marcin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCM Registration Token is equal to registration_id. As I mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671576/4625829):

An FCM Token, or much commonly known as a `registrationToken` like in [[image]google-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging). As described in the GCM docs:

> An ID issued by the GCM connection servers to the client app that allows it to receive messages. Note that registration tokens must be kept secret.

Different terms point to the same thing. The format for the registration token may also vary as seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32809847/4625829):

> The GCM registration token is usually around 140 chars in length, and can contain colons, underscores and hyphens. Maximum size is supposed to be 4k.

Though I'm not entirely sure with regards to the character length, I think I've read on a post here somewhere that it may exceed that number. Do search around.

Comment: AFAIK, yeah. I think I've encountered a registration token like that before.. Do try it. You can never know for sure if you don't test it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

gcm.register() is deprecated. use [instance id](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) method with token instead.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid

> **GCM register()** is deprecated starting May 28, 2015. New app
>   development should use the **Instance ID API** to handle the creation,
>   rotation, and updating of registration tokens. For more information,
>   see Registering Client Apps and Set up a GCM Client App on Android.

Comment: I know that . register() is deprecated. I didn't used it. I used the instance id. Like in the link i posted is shown. My question is only about the Chars before the Colon an the Colon itself.

Comment: use tokens insstead of former regids