# GCM/FCM Registration ID goes shorter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

The RegID for Android APP is keeping 152 characters for years. But I just noticed that this week, when I ask for a RegID from GCM(FCM), its length is now 140 characters, shorter than usual.

Is there any news that they're going to change their RegID length recently? This will affect how I configure my DB table.

**Update**
And NO! I'm not asking about GCM 4k length or anything about MAXIMUM! What I'm interested is the Length for current and next few years. Because that is what might affect my DB and Program's parameter check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of an FCM registration ID token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959417/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-fcm-registration-id-token)

Comment: In general, the length (and format) of the token varies and is subject to change depending on how Google needs it to be. For variables with that *randomness*, it'll be wiser to simply be able to check the *validity* of the tokens instead of length/format. But to answer your question -- No, there is no news about any token format related changes, nor is there any reference you could refer to as to what it would be in the years to come.

Comment: Ok, I see... Sigh... guess I gotta change my RegEx to check this RegID with [32,] and hope the Google don't make it shorter than 32.